# Will installing the stock screen recording app from a different model still record internal audio?

Tags: permissions, 9.0-pie, video-recording

My LGV30 phone running on Android 9 has a built-in screen recorder, but it displays an on-screen timer that can't be removed. On newer models (LGV40, LGV50) running on Android 10/11 this timer can be toggled off. I know apps downloaded from the Google Playstore can't record internal sound on Android 9. Before I download apk files from untrusted sources, I wanted to verify if installing the new version will still record internal audio or would it require root permission?

Comment: try if these apps work.. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-record-internal-audio-in-Android-9-without-earphones-and-without-rooting and https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-how-to-record-internal-audio-t3848927

Comment: @Aayush Thanks for the links. I tried the app from the second link but it requires root to record internal audio only. Basically all I want to know is if downloading an APK made by LG on my LG phone will update my current LG recording app which has internal audio recording, or will it be installed as a second app with no root access?